# Create Oracle database and schema programmatically ADO.NET

Tags: c#, database, oracle, ado.net, schema

How can I create a oracle database programmatically in ADO.NET and a schema for it with userId + password so I can just go to my non-favorite tool the sql oracle developer tool where I just create a connection entering:

- connectionstring name
- UserId(schema)
- password

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done it with SQL before but never tried with ADO.NET ...

```
string connectionString = "...";
string oracleDataPath = "C:\\PATH_TO_ORADATA\\";

string username = "NEW_USER";
string password = "NEW_PWD";
string schema = "NEW_SCHEMA";

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLESPACE \"" + schema + "\" DATAFILE '" + oracleDataPath + schema + ".DBF' SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE USER \"" + username + "\" IDENTIFIED BY \"" + password + "\" DEFAULT TABLESPACE \"" + schema + "\" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "GRANT CONNECT TO \"" + username + "\"";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER USER \"" + username + "\" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON \"" + schema + "\"";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Use the ADMIN/DBA account on the connection string.
Set oracleDataPath with the path where your Oracle keeps its data files.

Let me know if it works :-)