# Create a database programmatically on an Oracle server ado.net c#

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I want to create a new database on a remote Oracle server, I see an example from the post [Create Oracle database and schema programmatically ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056794/create-oracle-database-and-schema-programmatically-ado-net), but in this post the database is on a local server:

```
string oracleDataPath = "C:\\PATH_TO_ORADATA\\";
```

I need to do the same but on a remote server.

Thanks in advance for help me.

Comment: Creating an entire database is an installation task so probably belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com). What is an Oracle Server?

Comment: If you really want to create an Oracle database, you may be out of luck.  If the database doesn't already exist, ADO has nothing to connect to.  If we assume that you're using the enterprise edition 12.1 or later and that the server already has an Oracle CDB installed and that you want to create a PDB in that CDB then it would be possible.  Or if you're really just trying to create a schema (with or without a tablespace) as the linked question does, that would be possible.  Or maybe you're trying to do something else...

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle 11g R2, but I want to create the program independent of what database is.

It has to be done, if it can be done on a local server, it should be able to be done on a remote server.

I already did it with SQL Server.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. The command will always be executed on and by the server, not the client. You _do_ however need to know where a specific server stores the database files.

Comment: "Database" means something entirely different in SQL Server to what it means in Oracle, so it would be worth clarifying exactly what you are trying to achieve.